# Reload page after message faded out

Tags: c#, webforms

I want to reload the page after a message is displayed.
Here is my code.

ASPX:

```
<div id="MyMsg" style="display:none;color:red; text-align: center;" runat="server">
    <h2>This card has expired</h2>
    <h2>Please see front desk</h2>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function () {
    $('#MyMsg').fadeOut('fast');
    }, 5000) // <-- time in milliseconds
    window.location.reload();    
</script>
```

C#:

```
{
    MyMsg.Style.Add("display", "normal");
    btnSubmit.Enabled = false;
    IDCard.Text = "";
    IDCard.Visible = true;
    IDCard.Focus();
}
```

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

How can I reload the page in this script

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#MyMsg').fadeOut('fast');
}, 5000); // <-- time in milliseconds
```

Should it be like this
When i try this the page never starts at all

```
<script>
//setTimeout(function () {
//    $('#MyMsg').fadeOut('fast');
//}, 5000); // <-- time in milliseconds

const fadePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $('#MyMsg').fadeOut('fast');
    resolve();
});

// Now invoke the fadePromise and use then-block
fadePromise.then(() => {
    window.location.reload();
});
```

Comment: Is there something that is not working in your code? What have you tried? What kind of errors/problems did you face?

Comment: The code is working
But i want to reload the hole page after the message faded out
So it reloads like i started it for the first time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the window reload inside the setTimeout() instead, like so:

```html
<script>
    setTimeout(window.location.reload, 5000);
</script>
```

Unless fading is mandatory, in which case, you could call the reload function a bit late, like this:

```html
<script>
    // fade after 5 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
       $('#MyMsg').fadeOut('fast');
    }, 5000);

    // on 6th second, reload the page
    setTimeout(window.location.reload, 6000);
</script>
```

P.S: I know it has been a month old, but I sincerely hope that this helps you, if you have not found it already on your own :)

Comment: And is this a javascript?
Should i use both under 1 <script> or seperate?

Comment: Yes, it is a javascript code snippet. Use it inside that <script> tag.

Comment: I've added <script> tags in my answer for better understanding.

Comment: When i try with that the page wont load at all

Comment: I see that you've tried this and it is still not working. What is your use case? I mean is it like you want the text to show for 5 seconds and then reload the page? If so, the page will keep reloading again and again, in an endless loop. Could you instead use a button and call a function that does the displaying and reloading work on click event?

Comment: The page works like this
Scanning membercard, checking if the card is valid
If not, it shows the message and after 5 seconds the message fading away and then i want the page to be ready for the next card
Hope you understand what i mean, i don't want the person needed to click on anything when the card is not valid

Comment: Anyone who has any idea ho i can perform this?

Comment: Hey @Ace287, it has been more than a month and I was going through all my answers, to see if I missed answering someone. If you're still facing the problem, I've updated my answer. I think this time it would work! Let me know. Cheers!